# Append data after checking a condition

Tags: if-statement, sas, conditional-statements, append

I have a yearly table which on a monthly basis will append data from another table. However, I need to check the max date on the monthly table before appending it. If the max date on monthly is same as YTD, then do not append else append. How can I achieve this in SAS.

I tried using append but don't know how to check the dates before appending.

Comment: Provide some detail.  Name of date variable that you want to take the maximum of. Name of the dataset that contains that variable.  What is YTD? Is that another date variable? Something else?  What is the name of the dataset that is being appended to?  What is the name of the dataset to append? Is it the same dataset as the one that is used to calculate the maximum date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro.
First, insert the last year/month id on a variable and preper a macro to execute the append operation:

```
proc sql;
select max(yourDtcolumn) into : var
from yourTable;
quit;

%macro append;
   proc sql;
     insert into yourtable
      select * from sourcetable;
    quit;
%mend;
```

then, verify if the variable are the same:

```
%macro verify;
%if &var > &curMonth %then %do;
    %append;
%end;
%mend;
```

finally, you call the macro to execute:

```
%verify;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I want to add format to the date but the format date9. for  &var is printing it with all xxxxx. Is that a setting on my system or there is a workaround to see the date ?

Comment: Did you mean '********'?  If you try to display a datetime value (number of seconds) as if it was a date value (number of days) using the DATE9. format then result (if SAS could do it) would be too large to fit into 9 characters since the year part would be more than 4 digits.

Comment: The date is not holding seconds, it is in date format in sql.  What format can i use to display it on my log? Also the insert is working but it throws warning message of Character expression will be truncated when assigned to character column NAME ? Is this because of different format.

Comment: When you throw date into variables, SAS automatically change it to sasdate format. Remember, the first date on SAS is 1960-01-01 and in many systems, the first date is 1900-01-01, so there are 21916 days of difference. So, the date 2022-12-06 is 22985. The answer below can not be the most elegant, but is easy to implement:
    
    data _null_;
    call symput('var2', 
    cat(put(year(&var), z4.), - , put(month(&var), z2.), - ,put(day(&var), z2.));
    run;
    %put &var2;

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the check, and simply stack the existing data (excluding the current month, if it exists) and the new data.

```
/* Get period from new data */
proc sql ;
  select min(period) into :LATEST
  from new ;
quit ;

/* Append new to master, and save back master */
data perm.master ;
  set perm.master (where=(period < &LATEST))
      new ;
run ;
```

Comment: The monthly which is the new table in the example above will only have a month of data , also it may not be current month, it could be two months old. I just have to ensure the set does not duplicate the data. Would it still make sense to check in the where clause?